# Two foreign keys in one table using SQL Server in asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I've created `BidTable` in which I've used two foreign keys i.e ID from `Reg` table & `CarID` from `SubmitAdd` table.

ID from `Reg` table is fetched by comparison of username with current session's username while `CarID` is fetched by comparing query string `ID` with `CarID`.

The problem is when I use both of them in `BidTable` as foreign keys, `BidTable` can not fetch both of their data. But when I use them separately, for example I use only `ID` from `Reg` in `BidTable` as a foreign key, it works perfectly.

Here's the code:

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONN"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
{
    SqlCommand cmdd2 = new SqlCommand("select * from SubmitAdd where CarID='"+ Request.QueryString["id"].ToString() + "'", con);//taking CarID from QueryString
    con.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter sdda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdd2);
    DataTable dtt = new DataTable();
    sdda.Fill(dtt);

    SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("select * from Reg where username='"+ Session["USERNAME"] + "'", con);

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);       

    if (dtt.Rows.Count != 0 && dt.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0][0]); // Get Registration ID from Reg Table
        int CarID = Convert.ToInt32(dtt.Rows[0][0]);// Get CarID from SubmitAdd Table

        string ss = "insert into BidTable values('" + id + "','" + CarID + "','" + TextBid.Text + "')";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(ss, con);

        SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        sda2.Fill(dt2);
    }
}
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check join while fetching records, if you dont have either category id or userid and if you are using inner join then records will be ommited. Use left join.